# Outputting handlebars from controller to directive is not binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive which for all other cases works fine:

```
.directive('breadcrumbs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: '<ul class="breadcrumb offset2" ng-show="breadcrumbs">'
                +'<li ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs">'
                    +'<span ng-hide="crumb[1]">{{crumb[0]}}</span>'
                    +'<a ng-show="crumb[1]" href="#{{crumb[1]}}">{{crumb[0]}}</a>'
                    +'<span ng-show="crumb[1]" class="divider">/</span>'
                +'</li>'
            +'</ul>'
    }
}
```

It takes an array of "crumbs" and each crumb is an array holding the `['title', 'href']`, for instance:

```
$scope.breadcrumbs = [ ['Home', '/'], ['Projects', '/project'], ['Add', ''] ]
```

If the `href` is empty then `ngShow`/`ngHide` combine to hide the link and only output the text.

Where this becomes a problem is when I want to output a $scope variable from the controller in the breadcrumbs, for instance:

```
var ProjectViewCtrl = function ($scope, $routeParams, Project) {
    $scope.project = Project.get({id: $routeParams.id})
    $scope.breadcrumbs = [ ['Home', '/'], ['Projects', '/project'], ['{{project.name}}', ''] ]
}
```

The intention is that `{{project.name}}` is output in the last element of the breadcrumbs, and then once `Project.get` completes, the breadcrumbs are updated along with everything else in the controller template. Unfortunately this doesn't happen, and the text `{{project.name}}` is output to the page and never updates.

I know an alternative would be to set the breadcrumbs in the `Project.get` success callback, but that wouldn't really be binding, I'd just be updating the value, and therefore negating one of the main reasons for using Angular :)

Comment: loop over paths only and put name expression directly in directive template after `ng-repeat`

Comment: That's a pretty good plan B actually, but I'd first like to see if my problem can be solved head-on in the pursuit of knowledge. Good idea though thanks :)

Comment: putting expression in a javascript array make little sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reffer to this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BJP3v/1/. `ng-bind` is used to bind the dynamic project name to the view.

Then to test whether the binding is working or not, a `test` method is created in the controllers scope.
While the button is pressed, the project name is updated. Please put the updating of project name inside the callback of the `$http` call or `$resource` call